# can't compile code using struct tms

Tags: time, compiler-errors, tms

```
#if defined(HAVE_TIMES)
#include <unistd.h>
static double cycles_diff(struct tms *a,struct tms *b)
{

      clock_t aa = a->tms_utime  +
                   a->tms_stime  +
                   a->tms_cutime +
                   a->tms_cstime;

      clock_t bb = b->tmstms_utime
            +      b->tms_stime
            +      b->tms_cutime
            +      b->tms_cstime;

      return (aa-bb)/(double)sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
  }
}
```

This gives errors

> incomplete type declaration of struc tms

and

> sysconf was not declared

Answer (score 1):

[According to the manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Processor-Time.html) you need to `#include <sys/times.h>`